# Regular Expression for carriage return occuring at begining or end file

Tags: regex

I am looking for a way to remove 'stray' carriage returns occurring at the beginning or end of a file. ie:

```
\r\n <-- remove this guy
some stuff to say \r\n
some more stuff to say \r\n
\r\n <-- remove this guy
```

How would you match \r\n followed by 'nothing' or preceded by 'nothing'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(\r\n)+|\r\n(\r\n)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language either the following regex in multiline mode:

```
^\r\n|\r\n$
```

Or this regex:

```
\A\r\n|\r\n\z
```

The first one works in e.g. perl (where ^ and $ match beginning/end of line in single-line mode and beginning/end of string in multiline mode). The latter works in e.g. ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` version that should print out the stripped file:

```
 sed -i .bak -e '/./,$!d' -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' foo.txt
```

The `-i` tells it to perform the edit in-place and the `.bak` tells it to back up the original with a `.bak` extension first. If memory is a concern, you can use `''` instead of `.bak` and no backup will be made. I don't recommend unless absolutely necessary, though.

The first command (`'/./,$!d'` should get rid of all leading blank lines), and the rest is to handle all trailing blank lines.

See [this list of handy `sed` 1-liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for other interesting things you can chain together.

Answer (score 0):

`^\s+|\s+$`

```
\s is whitespace (space, \r, \n, tab)
+ is saying 1 or more
$ is saying at the end of the input
^ is saying at the start of the input
```

Comment: He wants to remove only the \r\n

Comment: In most implementations $ and ^ refer to the beginning/end of the line, not the whole string, unless you specifically enable multiline mode.

Comment: @Thiyagaraj: he said *\r\n followed by 'nothing' or preceded by 'nothing'* so I guessed he meant spaces.
@sepp2k: correct